# taking one byte from bytearray python

Tags: python, arrays

how can I take one of this byte from bytearray (I need it in the from of byte not an integer)

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x87\x0b\x1e\x9e\xc9\xde\xb7\n+\x92\n\x03\t')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of appropriately formatting the output - the internal value is not changed:

```
x = bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x87\x0b\x1e\x9e\xc9\xde\xb7\n+\x92\n\x03\t')
print("{:02x}".format(x[0]))
```

gives correctly:

```
01
```

If you absolutely need to retain the bytes property, go for something like

```
y = bytes([x[5]])
print(y)
```

which will then give you

```
b'\x9e'
```